# export Hooks in React for Nested Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm exporting hooks with nested components so that the parent can toggle state of a child. How can I make this toggle work with hooks instead of classic classes or old school functions?

**Child Component**

```js
export let visible;
export let setVisible = () => {};

export const ToggleSwitch = () => {
    const [visible, setVisibile] = useState(false);
    return visible && (
       <MyComponent />
    )
}
```

**Parent**

```html
import * as ToggleSwitch from "ToggleSwitch";

export const Parent: React.FC<props> = (props) => {
    return (
       <div>
          <button onClick={() => ToggleSwitch.setVisible(true)} />
       </div>
    )
}
```

> Error: Linter says [setVisible] is unused variable in the child... (but required in the parent)

Comment: `setVisible` isn't used in `ToggleSwitch`, so this is not unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You can move visible state to parent like this:

```
const Child = ({ visible }) => {
    return visible && <h2>Child</h2>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <Child visible={visible} />
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(visible => !visible)}>
            Toggle
        </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you have many child-components you should make more complex logic in `setVisible`. Put object to useState where properties of that object will be all names(Ids) of  child-components

Comment: This is clean and works great! What if you want to pass the hook to a sibling component:

* Parent contains the hook
* Child contains view
* Sibling renders the view

Answer (score 0):

as you know React is one-way data binding so if you wanna pass any props or state you have only one way to do that by passing it from parent to child component and if the logic becomes bigger you have to make it as a global state by using state management library or context API with react hooks use reducer and use effect.